# How to recreate a context menu with a popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic UI and they don't have context menus for some reason. I'm trying to recreate the functionality, and I'm close, but can't figure out this one part.

For example, this popup: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup#popup-example-hide-on-scroll

When you click it, it goes at a certain position such as:

```
top lefttop rightbottom rightbottom leftright centerleft centertop centerbottom center
```

Since I'm trying to recreate context menu functionality, I need it to appear at the clicked mouse position instead.

Is this possible?